# Lucene 4.0: TermStats is not public in TermStats; cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: lucene

I have two questions regarding Lucene 4.0:
1) I would like to change sorting in Lucene, so I created my own tfidf class and then called  TermStats constructor

```
    ts[t] = new TermStats( contents[t].field,contents[t].termtext, contents[t].docFreq, tfidf);
```

but the message is

```
    TermStats(String,BytesRef,int,long) is not public in TermStats; cannot be accessed from outside package
```

Does anybody know, whether I really do not have a way to change it?

2) Does Lucene, indeed, calculate tf*idf or just term frequency (tf)? I am asking because I have read about just term frequency but the contructor accepts docFreq which is related with idf.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Generally, you would rely on Lucene to pass `TermStatistics` objects into the [`computeWeight`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html#computeWeight%28float,%20org.apache.lucene.search.CollectionStatistics,%20org.apache.lucene.search.TermStatistics...%29) method of your custom `Similarity` implementation, rather than constructing them yourself.

If you need to acquire them directly, you could accomplish that by calling [`IndexSearcher.termStatistics`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#termStatistics%28org.apache.lucene.index.Term,%20org.apache.lucene.index.TermContext%29) (you'll need to pass in the appropriate `TermContext` to that call, created using the static method [`TermContext.build`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/TermContext.html#build%28org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReaderContext,%20org.apache.lucene.index.Term,%20boolean%29)).

2 - Yes, Lucene's [DefaultSimilarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/DefaultSimilarity.html) is an implementation of it's [TFIDFSimilarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html), which, as implied, does factor in idf scoring.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer! Ok, so to sum up the ranking that Lucene retuns is a result of a tf*idf calculation. In any case, if I would like to affect it, I would apply my calculations on top of Lucene's ranking without calling any TermStats extractor. I tried it implementing my own TFIDF class. I have to feed this class with termfrequency and other parameters. To get termfrequency  I use  termStats[t].totalTermFreq but it always returns zero. Whilst termStats[t].docFreq returns the number of docs the term appears. Do you have any idea why is that happening? Thank you.

Comment: Another thiing that I realize is that termStats[t].totalTermFreq does not return termfrequency but it is Lucene's result for tf*idf. If this is true, then a) why I am getting always zero and b) how can I get simple TF without IDF?

Comment: a) At a guess, the terms aren't indexed correctly for this.  Are you indexing the field with at least `FieldInfo.IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS`?  b) To use the default scoring algorithm without idf scoring: Create a custom Similarity, Extending `DefaultSimilarity`, and override the method `idf` with one that simply returns 1.0.